# World of Warcraft (Online Game) Server Development

Tags: world-of-warcraft

**I want to develope a server for World Of Warcraft. Where can i find a reference for this?**
I got Mangos source code already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't, because it's against the law.

Blizzard recently sued a company for doing this, and were awarded $88 million in damages. So unless you have a couple million dollars in legal penalties lying around, you simply **don't do it**.

Reference: http://www.bit-tech.net/news/gaming/2010/08/17/blizzard-sues-private-wow-server-operator/1

Comment: That may be. There are also many examples of crime families, insider trading, and pirated software. This doesn't make them legal, and that doesn't mean the SO community supports them.

Comment: **You right.I didn't know that this is illegal**

Comment: **This is not true.** - I mean, **having a WoW server in itself**. What **IS** "illegal" resp. against the licence of WoW is **REVERSE ENGINEERING** of WoW. Also it depends on a current legal system in the server's country/federation/union. But you know - how would you develop something FOR wow without reverse engineering right ... I think you get the picture :) Another thing is copyright/author law. Theoretically if you'd make a custom database and server-app of a game that just "happens" to also work with the WoW client, **that** would be completely legal :-)

Comment: Also the $88mils lawsuit - the defendant didn't respond to the suit, so it was "about them without them" => the default sentence in favour of Blizzard and THAT much money. REAL financial damage, and that IF and ONLY IF all players would otherwise be keen to buy official subscription would be `$6,405,000` MAXIMUM + some reasonable fine could be like 2 times that, so result could be around `$12,000,000` if the case would be defended.
**Please note** that the case was won mainly on these things: people were paying the server, there were a lot people and copyright => simply copying WoW=>illlegal

Comment: @jave.web No, it is illegal to have a WoW server due to copyright infringement, no matter what the technical reverse engineering is or is not involved.

Comment: @corsiKa there is **NO** copyright infringement in your **own** code x) **never was, never will be**. What could be (laws vary) copyright infringement would be if you'd *propagate* this as a WoW server. Also please **note the difference** between WoW-client-compatible server and WoW-copy-server (with same database, content, ...)

Comment: @jave.web I don't know how to say this, but I'm not talking about "a server that can be connected to by a WoW client" - I'm talking about, as in the 10 year old question, a WoW server. You cannot use any kind of derivative work without violating copyright. So you can keep screaming that it's not illegal, but you're changing the definition and then saying it's illegal - so please, just stop. I accept that what you're describing (writing a server that accepts the same protocols used by a WoW client) is not illegal. But while writing a World of JaveWebCraft server isn't illegal, a WoW server is.

Comment: @corsiKa Chill out, was just explaining. I admit my 1st comment was a bit misleading - point was - if your work (that even can resamble WoW) is distinct enough and don't use reverse engeneering, it's not against copyright laws. **Main issue, is profiting:**, I cite: "Derivative Works: Copy or reproduce (except as provided in Section 1.B.), translate, reverse engineer, derive source code from, modify, disassemble, decompile, or create derivative works based on or related to the Platform." - Section 1.B - "You may use the Platform for your personal and non-commercial entertainment purposes only"

Comment: Note that THAT is the main thing they won the lawsuit over :-)

Comment: You can tell me to chill out, but I'm not the one necromancing a 10 year old question to say the answer is wrong when it is, in fact, not wrong. Also, what are you citing? Section 1.B of what?